# Create a require() alias function

Tags: php, function, class

I have a class with this function:

```
public function loadTemplate($template)
{
    return require "templates/$template.php";
}
```

It's fine, but I have a problem with it.

Let's say I have this code:

```
require('class.php');    
$class = new ClassName; // ClassName is the class which contains the function loadTemplate()
$name = 'Jerry';
$class->loadTemplate('myname');
```

And *"myname.php"* is:

```
<?php
echo "My name is $name.";
```

In this case I get an error because *"myname.php"* is actually included in the file of the class and so **$name** is undefined.

How do I overcome this problem?

Comment: Honestly, I would suggest that you don't design your application this way.  Alternatively, you would need to pass in the "variables" to your loadTemplate method some how, and then have that pass them through to the $template somehow.

Comment: What do you think would be a better solution?

Comment: "use, analyze and learn from existing, tried&tested templating systems" would be one option.

Comment: You might want to have a look at the [`__DIR__`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) constant.

Answer (score 1):

Not discussing whether that's the best design, here's how you can do it.

```
public function loadTemplate($template, $vars)
{
    extract($vars);
    ob_start();
    require "templates/$template.php";
    $viewContent = ob_get_contents();
    ob_get_clean();
    return $viewContent;
}
```

Pass your variables as an associative array:

```
$vars = ['name' => 'Jerry']
```

And then output it:

```
echo $class->loadTemplate('myname', $vars);
```

What this does is, it creates variables from the array and loads the view, but with the "ob_" functions we are capturing the output buffer and then echoing it if we want.

You could probably get away without using ob_ just by echoing the require method as you were trying. I'd say give it a go and use what you prefer.